# How to answer a question that's on hold?

Tags: support

I know what a specific question is talking about, and I have the answer to it, but 5 people have voted it as 'unclear what you're asking'. I know exactly what they're asking and I can fix it... so what should I do?

EDIT: [The screen freezes when u are trying to find a skin pack](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/323797/the-screen-freezes-when-u-are-trying-to-find-a-skin-pack)

here is said question

Comment: Pro tip: Linking the question here would help bring it to a wider audience as well to vote on reopening it.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're sure you're understanding the question correctly, you should edit it in order to make it clearer for everyone else.
When a closed question is edited, it is nominated for reopening, and if people believe it is now clear enough to be answered, they will vote to reopen it.
After that, you'll be able to answer the question.

Comment: That said, editing is not allowed to change the intent of the question.  If you suggest an edit that's a radical change, chances are good it won't be approved.

Comment: here, link added. @TimmyJim